from encoder import inference as encoder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encoder'. Trying to install Voice-Cloning with pip
I'm trying to install the Voice-Cloning Library with pip.
Reference: https://pypi.org/project/Voice-Cloning/
And I get the error in this line: from voice_cloning.generation import *
I get this error:     from encoder import inference as encoder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encoder'
I tried using python 3.8 and 3.9
I tried to run the code on MacOS (Apple Silicon)

Consider using a library whose git repository hasn't been deleted.

Please post your full error traceback.

@Gaberocksall No necessary deleted. Could be a private repo. GitHub returns error 404 for repos for which the viewer is not authenticated.

Leon, the code seems to be buggy; it must be from voice_cloning.encoder import…. The code worked in Python 2 but stopped working in Py3. There're probably other bugs so my advice is to forge this package.
